# Two dialog box functions under one Private Sub

Tags: excel, vba, dialog

I am trying to get two dialog boxes to work under the Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range). They should pop up whenever someone enters a certain value into the range. The first one works fine but the second doesn't show at all. Below is the code I am using.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Range("J2:J54")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Value <> "Transportation" Then Exit Sub
     MsgBox "TRANSPORTATION: Remember tolls."
  If Target.Value <> "Guiding" Then Exit Sub
     MsgBox "GUIDING: Remember to add 10%."
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me see where I am going wrong?

Comment: you have exit sub in the first if statement.  nest your second if statement so the exit sub shows up only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exiting the sub at each point. Try turning your logic round, viz:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("J2:J54")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "Transportation" Then
        MsgBox "TRANSPORTATION: Remember tolls."
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Guiding" Then
        MsgBox "GUIDING: Remember to add 10%."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate possibility might be to use `Select Case`, checking first `If Not Intersect... Is Nothing` as opposed to exiting the sub if `If Intersect...Is Nothing`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J2:J54")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Transportation"
                MsgBox "TRANSPORTATION: Remember tolls."
            Case "Guiding"
                MsgBox "GUIDING: Remember to add 10%."
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Or combine into one line if the first word in the message box always corresponds to Target?

Comment: @SJR yes also possible, although maybe slightly more verbose.

Comment: Actually don't think that would work anyway as the message is different.

Comment: @SJR possible right if you added `Case Else, Exit Sub` and then "built up" the `MsgBox` at the end with `Target` and the changing portion of the message, e.g. "Remember tolls" - still, it'd be overkill.